# Getting frequency from a pixel value for Web Audio API EQ

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm creating an visual EQ using the Web Audio API and canvas. I am plotting frequencies in a logarithmic graph on a HTML5 Canvas using the following function:

```
function frequencyToPixel(freq){
    var min = Math.log(graph.min)/Math.log(10)
    ,   max = Math.log(graph.max)/Math.log(10)
    ,   range = max-min
    ,   pixel = (Math.log(freq)/Math.log(10) - min) / range * canvas.width;
    return pixel;
}
```

I would like to also reverse this equation to get a function that returns the frequency that a particular pixel relates to. At the moment I'm using the following function but it's not producing the desired result. For example if I input 1000 into the above function it returns 434.93. I should therefore be able to put 434.93 into the below equation to return 1000;

```
function pixelToFrequency(pixel){
    var min = Math.log(graph.min)/Math.log(10)
    ,   max = Math.log(graph.max)/Math.log(10)
    ,   range = max-min
    ,   x = (pixel * canvas.width * range) + min
    ,   frequency = Math.pow(10, x);
    return frequency;
}
```

It's likely i've rearranged the equation in the wrong way so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function below works out the frequency for a given pixel on the logarithmic-scaled canvas frequency graph:

```
function pixelToFrequency(pixel){
    var min = Math.log(app.graph.min)/Math.log(10)
    ,   max = Math.log(app.graph.max)/Math.log(10)
    ,   range = max-min
    ,   frequency = Math.pow(10, pixel * (range / canvas.width) + min)
    return frequency;
}
```

Comment: ah, okay so It didn't like my E(). Didn't really feel like thinking about it in terms of Exponents. Glad I could be of some help even if it were minor.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, RobotEyes. Been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out (maths is not my strong point!)

Just a note, though: it's probably gonna be quicker to use the pre-calculated Math.log(10) value via Math.LN10. Will edit your answer to use this. Tell me off if you don't approve!

Comment: Glad it's helped someone. I know how you feel with the maths side of it. Your suggestion about the `Math.LN10` is good to stay in the comments - I think that's SO protocol - correct me if i'm wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

```
pixel = (Math.log(freq)/Math.log(10) - min) / range * canvas.width
```

Try this?
freq = E((Math.log(10) * (pixel * (range / canvas.width)))+ Math.log(graph.min))

See if that helps at all. Where E is the [Euler's Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) raised to the parameters in parenthesis. It might be equivalent to what you have there, I didn't look to closely too be honest. It's worth a shot though.

Comment: That didn't work either but after messing about with you're previous one I got it to work - so thanks! I'll post the working solution as an answer in case anyone else needs it someday.